python.invalid command name ".!canvas"
I am making a ping pong game, in the line code ball movement
ball.goto(ball.xcor() +2, ball.ycor() +2)

after run the code it appear me this error message
Exception has occurred: TclError
invalid command name ".!canvas"
  File "C:\Users\ELNOUR\Desktop\mypython\.idea\pingpong.py\main.py", line 29, in <module>
    ball.goto(ball.xcor() +2, ball.ycor() +2) 
    ~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!canvas"

I am trying to make the ball when hits the paddle , the score of the paddle increase and only one because it increase infinit untill I move the paddle

It is better to provide a [mre] so that we can just copy and execute to reproduce the issue.

The error message is telling you that the tkinter.Canvas object ball has been destroyed which is why ball.goto(...)/ball.xcor()/ball.ycor() fails. Without a minimal reproducible example, we cannot help you further

Oh ,thanks . I’ll do that
